# Как в компоненте RichEdit сделать нумерованный список?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как в компоненте RichEdit сделать нумерованный список?

Comment: SynEdit поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Ну типа так

```
var
s:String;
i:integer;
Begin
for i:=0 to RichEdit1.Lines.count-1 do 
begin
s:=RichEdit1.lines.Strings[i];
s:=IntToStr(i)+'. '+s;
RichEdit1.lines.Strings[i]:=s;
end;

end;
```

Comment: нумерованный список, а не нумерацию строк

Comment: ну так проверяй в цикле, и инкременируй номер.

Comment: нумерованный список это:  
1.  
2.  
3.  
4.

Comment: стандартного метода нет, реализуй сам способом который покажется самым удобным

Comment: есть маркированный, но нет нумерованного? оО

Comment: и маркированного нет в RichEdit, Этов формате RTF есть маркированный список, посмотрите в описании формата может есть и нумерованный.

Comment: маркированный есть - RichEdit1.Paragraph.Numbering := nsBullet;

Answer (score 1):

Перерыв кучу ссылок, я таки нашел [ответ](http://www.kansoftware.ru/?tid=3731), может кому еще понадобится.

Вот цитата из нее:

```
uses
   RichEdit;

 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   fmt: TParaformat2;
 begin
   FillChar(fmt, SizeOf(fmt), 0);
   fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(fmt);
   // The PARAFORMAT2 structure is used to set the numbering style. 
  // This is done through the following structure members: 
  fmt.dwMask := PFM_NUMBERING or PFM_NUMBERINGSTART or PFM_NUMBERINGSTYLE or
                 PFM_NUMBERINGTAB;
       // Set the following values (bitwise-or them together) to identify 
      // which of the remaining structure members are valid: 
      // PFM_NUMBERING, PFM_NUMBERINGSTART, PFM_NUMBERINGSTYLE, and PFM_NUMBERINGTAB 
  fmt.wNumbering := 2;
       //0 no numbering or bullets 
      //1 (PFN_BULLET) uses bullet character 
      //2 Uses Arabic numbers (1, 2, 3, ...). 
      //3 Uses lowercase letters (a, b, c, ...). 
      //4 Uses uppercase letters (A, B, C, ...). 
      //5 Uses lowercase Roman numerals (i, ii, iii, ...). 
      //6 Uses uppercase Roman numerals (I, II, III, ...). 
      //7 Uses a sequence of characters beginning with the Unicode 
      //  character specified by the wNumberingStart member. 
  fmt.wNumberingStart := 1;
       //  Starting value for numbering. 
  fmt.wNumberingStyle := $200;
       // Styles for numbering: 
      // 0 : Follows the number with a right parenthesis.  1) 
      // $100 : Encloses the number in parentheses.       (1) 
      // $200 : Follows the number with a period.          1. 
      // $300 : Displays only the number.                  1 
      // $400 : Continues a numbered list without applying the next number or bullet. 
      // $8000 : Starts a new number with wNumberingStart. 
  fmt.wNumberingTab := 1440 div 4;
   // Minimum space between a paragraph number and the paragraph text, in twips 

  RichEdit1.Perform(EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, lParam(@fmt));
 end;
```